# ListView is repopulated when pressed back button from Activity B to go to Activity A and again went to Activity B by explicit intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-fragmentactivity, android-loadermanager

From MainActivity when i goto HolidayActivity by using explicit intent i am able to see the LisView is populated with distinct elements within the fragment, After pressing back button i again goto MainActivity and when i again try to open HolidayActivity the ListView is populated again with duplicate elements, I have used LoaderManager, so when device is rotated there is no duplicate elements, the problems occurs only when i switch between activities as described above. I have also tried to Override methos onKeyDown() and onBackPresses() but nothing seems to work out. Point to be noted out here is that i am fetching the list items from server.

### HolidayActivity.java

```
public class HolidaysActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static String HOLIDAY_REQUEST_URL;
public static holidayAdapter adapter;
public static final String LOG_TAG = HolidaysActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static Context mcontext ;
public static Activity activity = null;
public static int list_id;
public static ListView listView_holiday;
/**
 * The {@link PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private static boolean studentLogin = false;
private static boolean employeeLogin = false;
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mcontext = this;
    activity = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_holidays);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        HolidaysActivity.this.finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    activity.finish();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_holidays, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<holidays>> {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.holidays_list, container, false);
        // condition for switching to student login in TabWidget for registering complain
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
            HOLIDAY_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.43.26/fetch_restricted_holidays.php";
            listView_holiday = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            adapter = new holidayAdapter(activity,new ArrayList<holidays>(),0);
            listView_holiday.setAdapter(adapter);
            LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
            loaderManager.initLoader(1,null,this);
        }
        //condition for switching to employee login in Tabwidget for registering complain
        else {

        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<holidays>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new HolidayLoader(activity,HOLIDAY_REQUEST_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<holidays>> loader, List<holidays> holidays) {
        adapter.clear();
        if(holidays!=null && !holidays.isEmpty()){
            adapter.addAll(holidays);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<holidays>> loader) {
        adapter.clear();
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Gazetted Holidays";
            case 1:
                return "Restricted Holidays";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout complainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.complain_LinearLayout);
    complainLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent complainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Complain.class);
            startActivity(complainIntent);
        }
    });
    LinearLayout holiday = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.holidays_LinearLayout);
    holiday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity( new Intent(MainActivity.this, HolidaysActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: don't clear adapter while reloading you need to Clear the list that holds the data from server. and then reload the list with data and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Thanks but where should i clear my list , i wrote holidays.clear() in onload finished() but on orientation the list view is gone.